# Request from WKWebView

Tags: swift

I'm working with VK Api. I want get token when page finished load. How to do this? And how send token to another controller?

```
class loginViewController: UIViewController {

    var _webView: WKWebView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(_webView)

        _webView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: _webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: _webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        self.view.addConstraints([height, width])

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4876947&scope=audio&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.30&response_type=token")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL : url!)
        _webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self._webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the API send the token to you?

Comment: @Cristik when page finished load, I can get it by _webView.URL?.absoluteString!

Comment: Ok, that answers the first part of  your question, about the second part there are multiple ways to do pass the token to the next controller, one dirty but easy would be to pass it via a property